# Terrible Redis benchmark results on 5.2.11, Lenovo P1 Gen 2

Tags: arch-linux, redis

I am getting some real terrible Redis benchmarks on my brand new, extremely high spec laptop (Lenovo P1 Gen 2)

```
~ % cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 158
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
```

```
 redis-benchmark 
====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 6.15 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
33.15% <= 2 milliseconds
91.81% <= 3 milliseconds
99.99% <= 4 milliseconds
100.00% <= 4 milliseconds
16265.45 requests per second

====== PING_BULK ======
  100000 requests completed in 6.15 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
32.82% <= 2 milliseconds
89.20% <= 3 milliseconds
99.97% <= 4 milliseconds
100.00% <= 4 milliseconds
16254.88 requests per second

====== SET ======
  100000 requests completed in 6.14 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

0.00% <= 1 milliseconds
33.01% <= 2 milliseconds
89.44% <= 3 milliseconds
99.99% <= 4 milliseconds
100.00% <= 4 milliseconds
16289.30 requests per second
```

An ancient MBP I have is pushing 60k for the SET, my desktop does 177935 for the set which is 10x more.

Desktop is running the same Kernel, able to repro this directly from the Arch installer after installing Redis. (booting from USB drive)

```
 ~ % uname -a
Linux laptop 5.2.11-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 29 08:09:36 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any idea how I would go about debugging this terrible network stack perf to `localhost`?

```
redis-server --version
Redis server v=5.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-5.2.0 bits=64 build=78473e0efb96880a
```

**EDIT**

Stuff gets a lot faster if I unload and reload wifi.

```
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe -r iwlmvm
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe -r cfg80211
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe -r iwlwifi
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe iwlwifi
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe cfg80211
[root@slaptop ~]# modprobe iwlmvm
[root@slaptop ~]# redis-benchmark 
====== PING_INLINE ======
  100000 requests completed in 0.61 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

100.00% <= 0 milliseconds
165016.50 requests per second

====== PING_BULK ======
  100000 requests completed in 0.63 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

100.00% <= 0 milliseconds
159744.41 requests per second

====== SET ======
  100000 requests completed in 0.60 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1
```

So I am guessing this is somewhat related to the order of operations when initializing networking. I wonder what...

Comment: First tool to use would be strace, probably running it in summarise mode. Here is a script that I use for PHP-FPM https://gist.github.com/Danack/de16db746dd2c6a29c8d , which might be of some use.

If you run that and compare it to similar run on your MBP using dtrace (or whatever the strace equivalent is) you should be able to see where the extra time is being spent.